# use ajax/postman to send files to google forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, postman, google-forms

How I can send files to google forms using ajax or postman app?

```
Im getting error with postman 401: 

Drive: Sorry, you can't view or download this file error
```

Comment: Could you please share the code that you have used that got this error?

Comment: Postman gived that error. Says 401 unauthorized. I removed limit of answers but still same issue. is it even possible to send files via postman or ajax to google forms? @TheGrandJ

Comment: You should be able to form a request to send files using form-data in Postman, whether google forms expects something specific you'd have to review their API. Can you post what your request looks like?

Comment: @socalcheesehead if I tryed to get their embed code of my Forms then it sayed "Embed isnt possible becuase in your forms has file upload" or something that so I think it is not possible.